# Error Gradle XML Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this problem when running gradle. If someone can help, thank you.

> C:\Users\kevin\AndroidStudioProjects\Groud\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_first.xml
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   Failed to execute aapt
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar -M \?\C:\Users\kevin\AndroidStudioProjects\Groud\app\build\intermediates\manifests\instant-run\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\kevin\AndroidStudioProjects\Groud\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \?\C:\Users\kevin\AndroidStudioProjects\Groud\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\kevin\AndroidStudioProjects\Groud\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_ --custom-package com.kevinladelfa.groud -0 apk --preferred-density xhdpi --output-text-symbols \?\C:\Users\kevin\AndroidStudioProjects\Groud\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
>   Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>   Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Error:(69) Error parsing XML: mismatched tag
>   Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar -M \?\C:\Users\kevin\AndroidStudioProjects\Groud\app\build\intermediates\manifests\instant-run\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\kevin\AndroidStudioProjects\Groud\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \?\C:\Users\kevin\AndroidStudioProjects\Groud\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\kevin\AndroidStudioProjects\Groud\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_ --custom-package com.kevinladelfa.groud -0 apk --preferred-density xhdpi --output-text-symbols \?\C:\Users\kevin\AndroidStudioProjects\Groud\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
>   C:\Users\kevin\AndroidStudioProjects\Groud\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_first.xml
>   Error:(69) Error parsing XML: mismatched tag

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.kevinladelfa.groud.FirstActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/firstActivityToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Primary"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Groud"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/firstActivityFragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBarLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center">


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/Details"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/navigation_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/navigation_selector"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_nav"
    android:id="@+id/navigation">
</FrameLayout>
```

My Main Activity.

```
package com.kevinladelfa.groud;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

//Instances
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar firstActivityToolbar;
BottomNavigationView navigation;
NestedScrollView firstActivityFragmentContainer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    //Objects
    firstActivityToolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.firstActivityToolbar);
    navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    firstActivityFragmentContainer = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.firstActivityFragmentContainer);

    //Fragment
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactionHome = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransactionHome.add(R.id.firstActivityFragmentContainer, new HomeFragment()).commit();

    //Navigation
    navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigationHome);

    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            switch (item.getItemId()){

                case R.id.navigationHome:

                    firstActivityFragmentContainer.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    transaction.replace(R.id.firstActivityFragmentContainer, new HomeFragment()).commit();

                    return true;

                case R.id.navigationConfigurate:

                    return true;

                case R.id.navigationFollow:

                    firstActivityFragmentContainer.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    transaction.replace(R.id.firstActivityFragmentContainer, new ProfileFragment()).commit();

                    return true;

                case R.id.navigationFriends:

                    return true;

                case R.id.navigationSearch:

                    return true;

            }

            return false;
        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: post also main class

Comment: okay, there add the main activity

Comment: check your gradle properties do you have android.enableAapt2=false

Comment: yes, I have android.enableAapt2 = false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove `android.enableAapt2=false` and also disable instant Run

Comment: did it fix your problem